# Angular 5 - change variable in app.config.json

Tags: angular

I am declaring an asset JSON config file at `.angular-cli.json` that I use as default. But in some case, I want to change some of it's values and I don't know how to do it, any idea?

`.angular-cli.json`:

```
{
  "apps": [{
    "root": "src",
    "outDir": "www",
    "assets": [
      "assets",
      "favicon.ico",
      "app.config.json"
    ]
  }]
}
```

`app.config.json`:

```
{
  "ecmHost": "https://xxxxxx.xxxx.xx",
  "bpmHost": "https://yyyyyy.yyyy.yy",
  "application": {
    "name": "name",
    "logo": "assets/xxxx.png",
    "copyright": "All rights reserved."
  }
}
```

I don't know if I explain myself well but, how can I change `ecmHost` variable?

Comment: Your `app.config.json` looks a lot like what `environment.ts` should be. If your goal is to have a file of constants and configuration values you want to be looking at the environments files in your project's root directory. No need to add extra files and use the assets property.

Comment: I think im not explain myself well, my goal here is change variables dynamically/runtime. i.e. start app with one value and after execute some action change that value

Comment: Ok I understood the goal. How are you reading the local `app.config.json` file (using httpClient maybe)? You should have an in-memory representation of the content of the file and you can easily change its values.. If you need to persist those changes you need to write the file and that's a real different story.

Comment: I think my problem is that i dont know exactly how this file is read(at least i think im nit using http to read that). I have a local js api that is dependency of my project and some how this api can get that variable. But basically im trying to read a external config file and set some variable based on what is in config.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to import that JSON, to do that you can either:

- send an http request using `httpClient`
- import using the Typescript loader with `import api from 'path/file.json'`
- import using node's require `const api = require('path/to/file.json')`.

Make sure to enable tsconfig options if you use `import` or `require`.

Once you have the api object you can manipulate it as a normal POJO, just accessing its properties.